# how to merge ical calendars

Tags: merge, calendar, icalendar

I have an issue I would like some advice on..
I am trying to merge multiple google calendars into one, so that all events from several ("descendant") accounts (e.g. test1@google.com, test2@google.com) are always synced in the "mother" account (e.g. mother@google.com).
I have multiple accounts at clients from which I have to send invites for people to book a meeting. The problem is that now they cant see the other times i am booked for my other accounts. That is why I need to be able to merge all of them together into the mother account so that all my appointments for all my accounts can be seen by everyone.
So to be clear, I need people to see my events in the calendar test1@google.com, when I've send an invite from test2@google.com. Preferably all accounts (test1, test2) are merged and synced/updated in real time in my main account mother@google.com.

Does anybody have any tips on how to get there? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve the same problem - the only solution I have found so far relies on using a 3rd party website - you can make a calendar with various sub-calendars merging into it, then share access to it with differing permissions. https://teamup.com

The free account is probably enough for what you need.